# clockwise 2d Matrix rotation

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multidimensional-array, rotation

I have the following code that rotates a matrix counter-clockwise 45 degrees, and can't figure out how to make it go clockwise. (Code provided by Sandeep Sharma at [Rotate numpy 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083943/rotate-numpy-2d-array/45769682#45769682))

```
def rotate45(array, clockwise = False):
rot = []
if clockwise == False:
    for i in range(len(array)):
        rot.append([0] * (len(array)+len(array[0])-1))
        for j in range(len(array[i])):
            rot[i][int(i + j)] = array[i][j]

# Thats where something should be changed, but I cant figure out what
else:
    for i in range(len(array)):
        rot.append([0] * (len(array)+len(array[0])-1))
        for j in range(len(array[i])):
            rot[i][int(i + j)] = array[i][j]

return rot
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "rotates a matrix" ? Can you show the desired output ?

Comment: I work on mnist, using plt to plot the 28x28 matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the linked post, can you not use scipy.ndimage.rotate ?

For example:

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
def rotateClockwise45(array):
    return rotate(array, -45)

# Rotate any amount:
# Use negative numbers for clockwise, positive for counter clockwise.
def rotate(array, angle):
    return rotate(array, angle)
```

Additionally, you can set the reshape flag to false when calling the rotate function if you want to preserve the original input dimensions. For example:

```
rotate(array, angle, reshape=False)
```